# How long does an IPv6 neighbour table entry last?

Tags: cisco, ipv6

I've been looking around in manuals and Cisco Books, but nowhere have I found how long an entry lives in the IPv6 Neighbour table. If that depends on the implementation, what is it for Cisco?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Cisco IOS the default cache timeout is "[14,400 seconds (4 hours)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/ipv6/command/reference/ipv6_book/ipv6_07.html#wp2374068)".

Comment: Hi Ricky Beam, I'm seeing this for the first time since I didn't subscribed to the thread. Wouldn't 4 hours be the time for IPv6 arp table? I end up reading the Neighbour Discovery Protocol RFC and is seams to be really short, here's more information about it:

http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4861#section-7.3.2